# Is there a way to add a 3rd, 4th and 5th y axis using Bokeh?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I would like to add multiple y axes to a bokeh plot (similar to the one achieved using matplotlib in the [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN58r.png) image).

Would this also be possible using bokeh? The resources I found demonstrate a second y axis.

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Pranit Iyengar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. To add a new axis to the figure `p` use `p.extra_y_ranges["my_new_axis_name"] = Range1d(...)`. Do not write `p.extra_y_ranges = {"my_new_axis_name": Range1d(...)}` if you want to add multiple axis, because this will overwrite and not extend the dictionary. Other [range objects](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#module-bokeh.models.ranges) are also valid, too.

### Minimal example

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d
output_notebook()

data_x = [1,2,3,4,5]
data_y = [1,2,3,4,5]
color = ['red', 'green', 'magenta', 'black']
p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=300)
p.line(data_x, data_y, color='blue')

for i, c in enumerate(color, start=1):
    name = f'extra_range_{i}'
    lable = f'extra range {i}'
    p.extra_y_ranges[name] = Range1d(start=0, end=10*i)

    p.add_layout(LinearAxis(axis_label=lable, y_range_name=name), 'left')
    p.line(data_x, data_y, color=c, y_range_name=name)
show(p)
```

### Output

[image: multiple axis example]

### Official example

See also the [twin axis example (axis)](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/axes/twin_axes.html) on the official webpage. This example uses the same syntax with only two axis. Another example is the [twin axis example for models](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/models/twin_axis.html).