# Separate range sliders for multiple y axes in bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, rangeslider, python-interactive

I  have multiple line plots to draw on a single figure and I am doing this using bokeh.plotting. Using

```
p0.line(), 

p0.extra_y_ranges(),
```

and

```
p0.add_layout(LinearAxes())
```

p0 being 1 bokeh figure.

[image: Example plot attached for reference.]

I would like to have range_sliders for each y axis separately on the right. Would this be possible using bokeh?

For the primary y axis, the range slider works fine using

```
# set up RangeSlider y_counts
range_slider_c = RangeSlider(
    title="c",
    start=-10,
    end=400,
    step=1,
    value=(-1, 300),
    height = 250,
    orientation='vertical',
    show_value= False,
    direction = 'rtl'
)
range_slider_c.js_link("value", p0.y_range, "start", attr_selector=0)
range_slider_c.js_link("value", p0.y_range, "end", attr_selector=1)
```

But I am unclear about how to call the additional y axes's ranges like I did for p0.y_range in js.link.

I hope I have been able to explain my requirements properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers is based on the answer on your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74572541/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-3rd-4th-and-5th-y-axis-using-bokeh).

As it is mentioned there, the extra y-ranges are saved in a dictionary with the keyword `extra_y_ranges`. Therefor you only have to change the `js_link` using `extra_y_ranges` with a valid name. For example `range_slider_c.js_link("value", p0.extra_y_ranges["c", "start", attr_selector=0)`.

### Complete minimal example

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d, CustomJS, RangeSlider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

data_x = [1,2,3,4,5]
data_y = [1,2,3,4,5]
color = ['red', 'green', 'magenta', 'black']
p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=300)
p.line(data_x, data_y, color='blue')

range_sliders = []
for i, c in enumerate(color, start=1):
    name = f'extra_range_{i}'
    lable = f'extra range {i}'
    p.extra_y_ranges[name] = Range1d(start=0, end=10*i)

    p.add_layout(LinearAxis(axis_label=lable, y_range_name=name), 'right')
    p.line(data_x, data_y, color=c, y_range_name=name)

    range_slider = RangeSlider(start=0, end=10*i, value=(1,9*i), step=1, title=f"Slider {lable}")
    range_slider.js_link("value", p.extra_y_ranges[name] , "start", attr_selector=0)
    range_slider.js_link("value", p.extra_y_ranges[name] , "end", attr_selector=1)

    range_sliders.append(range_slider)

show(column(range_sliders+[p]))
```

### Output

[image: multiple y-ranges with multiple sliders]

### Comment

To stack the sliders and the figure i use the `column` layout, which takes a list of bokeh objects. Other layouts are [available](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/layouts.html).

Comment: Thankyou for the precise instructions [mosc9575](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14058726/mosc9575)